# Enterprise Architect (EA) reverting special characters on diagrams

Tags: enterprise-architect

My diagrams must contain some special characters like ı,ğ and such. When I use these on EA they revert back to the closest related character like i,g,etc after I restart EA.

The project is shared so I can't easily migrate to jet4 as I have seen suggested on older posts. Is this still the only solution?

This happens on some machines only. We use EA13.

Things I have tried.

- Start-Preferences-General-Use Jet 4.0
- Start-Preferences-XML Specifications-Code Page:UTF-8
- Configure-Source Code Engineering-Code Page for source editing:UTF-8
- Control Panel-Languages: Same on every machine.
- OS language and version is the same (w10-Eng).

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Jet4 or a "real" database are the only options.

Comment: As Geert said. The Jet4 option is discussed on Sparx' forum in length.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Actually this IS the answer, so you should make it one.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Jet4 database or one of the *real* database systems is the only option.

The regular .eap files are in the Jet3.5 format and that format simply doesn't support unicode.

Since v14 Jet4 files have been given the .eapx extension.